# Unusual build/archive error in xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

**Issue**

When archiving and building in Xcode I get this strange compiling error.

[image: Error]

The first time this error has occurred, I just deleted it from the project because I realized it was unnecessary, but the error then moved to other files that have nothing to do with each other. There is no pattern.

*To Clarify*
- I examined the file in question and that it was existing in the path that it was complaining about.

**Solutions already tried**

- Cleaning project
- Deleting derived data
- Restarting project and computer
- Changing provision files

^ all in different orders

Nothing I have used so far has worked.

**Other**

I have never encountered the error and I have googled this error and achieved nothing since three hours ago.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit:

If this helps its a .m file

[image: error2]

**Update**

I tried archiving in Xcode 5 and I received the error `framework not found Metal for architecture armv7`. I found a few solutions

- `disabling modules within build settings` - cannot disable because the @import is required for a couple classes
- `linking the Metal framework` - still get the error `framework not found Metal`
- `disabling link frameworks automatically within build settings` - nothing results from this being disabled

Comment: Sounds like it might be a provisioning profile issue? Are you sure you're using a profile that is matched to the cert you're using to archive?

Comment: I use multiple provisioning profiles for different reasons. I have never had a problem with this before. How would I verify that?